# MATLAB Create an array from a for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

I have to create an array from the outputs of a for loop. For example, if the for loop was:

```
for i=[0.01, 0.02, 0.05]
    exp(i)
end
```

I should create an array such as

```
[exp(0.01) exp(0.02) exp(0.03)]
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Almost like you did :-)

```
V= [0.1 0.2 0.3]
R=exp(V)
```

Create a vector of values for which you want to compute a function and pass it as parameter.